# Нужна ли запятая перед тире в бессоюзном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Дано сложное предложение с бессоюзной и союзной связью:

> Евгений Алексеевич энергично потёр нос и так близко наклонился ко мне,
>   что я невольно отшатнулся – показалось, он хочет меня клюнуть.

Нужна ли запятая перед тире, закрывающая придаточное предложение? Можно ли найти правило на эту тему?

Answer (score 1):

[Евгений Алексеевич энергично потёр нос и так близко наклонился ко мне], (что я невольно отшатнулся), – [ показалось], (он хочет меня клюнуть).

Запятая и тире ставятся для обозначения «перелома» первоначальной конструкции, для указания,   *«с одной стороны, на расчлененность предложения, а с другой — на то, что та его часть, которая следует за этим знаком препинания, делает структурный поворот от предшествующей части под некоторым, большим или меньшим, „углом“*

*Комната наполнилась шумом отодвигаемых стульев, в углу вспыхнул огонёк спички, осветив кисть руки с длинными пальцами, испуганной курицей заклохтала какая то барышня, — Самгину было приятно смятение, вызванное его словами (М.Г.);*

Ср. также **бессоюзные сложные предложения, в которых между частями возможна постановка двоеточия:**

*К этому чувству присоединялась тоскливая зависть, — (:) как хорошо было бы обладать грубой дерзостью Кутузова, говорить в лицо людей то, что думаешь о них (М.Г.); Он было застонал, но уже гораздо легче, чем в первый раз, и вскоре натура взяла своё, — (:) назавтра же пошёл он как ни в чём не бывало гулять и стал выезжать в театры(Тын.); Послушайся моего совета, совета старого друга, — (:) не ходи туда.* https://studfiles.net/preview/395407/page:41/

У нас как раз предложение - сложная синтаксическая конструкция, состоящая из двух сложноподчинённых предложений, а они между собой связаны бессоюзно. Между ними тире, но возможно и двоеточие:

*Евгений Алексеевич энергично потёр нос и так близко наклонился ко мне, что я невольно отшатнулся(почему?): показалось, он хочет меня клюнуть.*

Это и есть условие постановки запятой и тире как единого знака: **чтобы разделить предложение на две части, обозначить "перелом" и  паузу,которая должна бы быть на месте двоеточия, но у нас тире, значит, запятая тоже нужна.**

Comment: Спасибо. Просто это предложение взято из современного романа, а там запятой нет. Мне кажется, что перед тире сейчас часто не ставят  закрывающую запятую, и я думала, что правила изменились. А можно считать, что это не единый знак, а сочетание запятой и тире?

Comment: Эти знаки относятся к факультативным. Возможен и другой подход. Если есть сложная конструкция из двух частей и эти части можно рассмотреть как два отдельных предложения, соединённых бессоюзно, то  между ними возможно поставить один из знаков, обозначающих отношения между ними, то есть или тире, или двоеточие. Так что отсутствие запятой не ошибка - более современный подход. Вы верно заметили, современные авторы редко прибегают к запятой и тире как единому знаку вместо  двоеточия.

Comment: Видимо, можно счесть и за сочетание закрывающей запятой и тире.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна. Обороты "что", "который", причастные, деепричастные и т.д. выделяются запятыми, независимо от окружающих их знаков (кроме точки, разумеется). Правило, вероятно, найти можно. Но я отвечаю, основываясь не на правиле, а на том, что задавал здесь аналогичный вопрос.

Comment: Два предложения в одном — уже основание нужности запятой.